# best practice for wicket and db access

Tags: java, database, jpa, wicket

So I'm writing a simple application and rather then fumble my way through it I wanted to see if someone can give advice on how to set this up.

I have a wicket app, that I'm basically going to do something like a forum app (I've been looking at the wicket guestbook example) however I want to persist these messages to a database. I would like to use a listview (or maybe a repeater) to display the messages. I have created the db (mysql) and tables, and created entity objects for them.

What is a best practice for interfacing wicket with the db. I think I need a loadabledetachablemodel but I'm open to suggestions.

Should I create a class that implements the loadabledetachable interface and do my transactions to the database in that class? Should I do a DAO? and load in the data in the model by calling methods in the DAO? I've been looking at examples and I'm confused on how to do this. I am already learning wicket and the whole JPA stuff so I really don't want to throw something like Spring on this. I need to be able to add/update/delete and I'm just trying to figure out where  is the best place to do this.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use simplest model like `Model` or `PropertyModel`. When rendering the page, load data from database into your model and display the data. When user press update button, read new value from model and then update to the database.

You don't need any `LoadableDetachableModel` right now since you're still learning the basic part of the wicket framework.

About DAO part, if you just want to focus on learning wicket, create a simple CRUD application without DAO class is okay. You can always refactor those code into DAO classes later anyway. But if you're trying to learn developing a web application, then you should create a DAO class and learn about the concept of [Multiple Tier Architecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture).

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good explanation in German - but the code is in English:

The solution extends the LoadableDetachableModel to hold an EntityFacade by storing the classname and performing the lookup on load().

I think the example from here:
http://hotchpotch-blog.de/2012/10/09/wrapping-eines-ejb-in-ein-loadabledetachablemodel/

can be extended to something like this (not production ready):

```
public class EjbModel extends LoadableDetachableModel {

/**
 * Get the name of the EJBInterface  type suitable for lookup.
 * 
 */
protected String ejbName;

public EjbModel(EJBInterface bean){
    //store the bean so it will get detached 
    super(bean)
    ejbName = bean.getSimpleName() + "Facade"; //not sure if + "Facade" is needed
}

@Override
protected EJBInterface  load() {
    EJBInterface  result = null;
    try {
        InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
        result = (EJBInterface ) ctx.lookup("java:module/" + ejbName);
    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(this.getClass().getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Error at JNDI lookup for " + getEjbName(), ex);
    }
    return result;
}
}
```

Comment: Please do not use external links to answer the questions. Put the information directly in your answer, and leave the reference to the site you used.